# Summarize column in multiple files in R

Tags: r, summary

I have multiple files which is formatted like:

```
> Test1.txt
            NameNo  Team  etc
1:         AS001-A.    8  773
2:         AS002-S.    7  631
3:         AS003-G.    8  970

> Test2.txt
            NameNo  Team  etc
1:         AB001-A.    2  773
2:         AB002-S.    6  631
3:         AB003-G.    6  970

> Test2.txt
            NameNo  Team  etc
1:         AR001-A.    1  773
2:         AR002-S.    1  631
3:         AR003-G.    1  970
```

Here is my code:

```
files <- list.files(pattern ="*.txt", full.names = TRUE) 
files
> files
Test1.txt
Test2.txt
Test3.txt
```

I then used `table(Team)` one by one.

I need to summarize column `Team`

Desired output:

```
Item      Team
Test1      7,8
Test2      2,6
Test3        1
```

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# get all the textfiles starting with "Test" 
list.files(pattern ="^Test.*\\.txt$") |>

  # loop through the files, reading them in, adding a column for their filename
  map_dfr(~read_csv(.) |> mutate(file = str_remove(.x, ".txt"))) |>

  # separate the weird format into columns using regex
  separate_wider_regex(`NameNo  Team  etc`, patterns = c("\\d+:\\s+", NameNo = "\\S+", "\\s+", Team = "\\d+", "\\s+", etc = "\\d+")) |>

  # get the unique teams for each file, sorted
  summarise(Team = paste0(sort(unique(`Team`)), collapse = ","), .by = file)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  file  Team 
  <chr> <chr>
1 Test1 7,8  
2 Test2 2,6  
3 Test3 1
```

If the row numbers aren't actually part of the files, you can do this:

```
f = list.files(pattern ="^Test.*\\.txt$")

tibble(Item = str_remove(f, "\\.txt"),
       Team = map_chr(f, ~read.table(., header = TRUE)$Team |> unique() |> sort()  |> paste0(collapse = ",")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
setwd('foo')
files <- list.files(pattern='.txt')
data.frame(Item=files, 
           Team=lapply(files, read.table) |> lapply(`[[`, 'Team') |> lapply(unique) |> lapply(sort) |> sapply(toString))
#        Item Team
# 1 Test1.txt 7, 8
# 2 Test2.txt 2, 6
# 3 Test3.txt    1
```

Comment: Jay do you reckon the strange formatting in OP's question is indicative of the files being strange? I ask because I read it literally, though I can see it not being the case

Comment: also, neat trick with `toString`! You learn something new every day 

Comment: @Mark The colons might indicate use of data.table